# Is there a way on include spring-javaformat as part of the build?

Tags: java, gradle

Currently I have to run

```bash
./gradlew format
```

then

```bash
./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport
```

each time in my terminal console (IntelliJ), so I'm wondering if there is a way to include the format as part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to include the format as part of the build

You can do this by writing:

```
build.dependsOn(format)
```

in your Groovy `build.gradle` script.